# Tensorflow: Input 2d float array as image

Tags: arrays, image, tensorflow, input, 2d

I am trying to use tensorflow for my 2D float data (or image, say values range 0.0-600.0) but don't know how.  I have seen examples for jpg and gif by using tf.io.decode_ but in my case the data is in a 2d float array.

I am guessing that "tf.io.decode_raw()" or "tf.convert_to_tensor()" might work but don't know how.

Does anyone have a simple example how to input a 2d float array into tf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes tf.convert_to_tensor() works , here is a sample code to convert a float32 2D array to tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
arr= np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]],np.float32)# put your image path or image , this step is loading and converting your image to numpy array 
print(arr)
converted_arr=tf.convert_to_tensor(arr,dtype=tf.float32)# this is converting the the numpy array further
print("\n\n\nconverted tensor is ")
print(converted_arr)
```